# Is "what on earth" still commonly used in real life? Is there any alternative that is not cursing or obscene?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage, offensive-language, minced-oaths

I'm a non-native speaker. When I was at school, we were taught that "on earth" is used for emphasis in questions such as:

> What on earth are you talking about?

However, from my experience (English movies, TV, online discussions, etc.), I seldom see people actually use the phrase "on earth".

From what I see, the most commonly used phrases that express basically the same meaning are "What the fuck..." and "What the hell...".

I don't like cursing or obscenity (call me old-fashioned), so here are my questions:

Is "on earth" still commonly used in real life?

Is there any alternative that is not cursing or obscene?

Comment: "On earth" is still common, as is "in the world" used the same way.

Comment: "What in the name of [expression]" is getting fairly commonplace, with [expression] ranging from pious to profane to vulgar to creative to intentionally pompous and elaborate...

Comment: So..  Anyone else also first think of [Carmen Sandiego](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen_Sandiego#Where_on_Earth_Is_Carmen_Sandiego.3F)?

Comment: Do you consider *"What the heck"* as cursing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a reason that such exclamations involve cursing, without it you simply don't get the impact and might as well not bother.  "What on earth was that" has a completely different impact as "WTF was that!?!"  More clinical and doesn't really indicate that it had a true impact or was shocking.

Comment: My go-to word is "bugger".. I think it is just as flexible f**k with just that little bit more acceptability in polite society. In reference to "what on earth", I think that is perfectly acceptable though: "what on earth do you mean?" But if you want to add just that little touch of colour, say "bugger it, what do you mean?"

Comment: "What the" (truncated ending) is also an option.  The listener may fill in the rest.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I don't know. Is "darn it" considered cursing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) look as follows:

```
                          BNC             COCA
                      TOTAL  SPOKEN   TOTAL  SPOKEN
                
what the hell          716     143    4668     408
what on earth          585      85     607      99
what the fuck           93      30     980       1
what the heck           31      15     671     294
what the devil          55       7     121       6
what in heaven's name   12       1      29       4
what the blazes          9       1       8       0
what the deuce           2       0       9       1 
what the flip            0       0       2       1
what the blank           0       0       0       0
```

As you can see, "what on earth" is still common on both sides of the pond, but relatively more common in the UK than in the US.

So let's look more closely at its popularity in the States. The [Corpus of Historical American English (COHA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) paints the following picture:

[image]

<sub>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words)</sub>

This suggests that indeed, both "what the hell" and "what the fuck" have been getting more popular in the recent decades.

Comment: Thanks. The corpora you mention cover both written and spoken English, and thus their results mean more to me than Google Books results.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Does what the blank indicate the sentence was truncated or that blank is actually said? I hear the truncated version spoken quite a lot more than either "what on earth" or "what in the world" nowadays, though never written.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA The new numbers puzzled me. "What the fuck" only has one spoken instance in COCA?

Comment: @Betty: That doesn't surprise me. The COCA sifts through [transcripts from non-scripted media interviews](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/help/spoken_e.asp) for that data, where the utterance is unlikely to occur. (Had they monitored, say, conversations at sports bars, I'm sure the frequency would have been much higher.) Another factor to consider is that the phrase might have even been spoken in an interview, but then 'bleeped out' for broadcast purposes, and subsequently transcribed as "What the [expletive deleted]?" which wouldn't register a search hit. Hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 18):

I realize that Ngrams have limitations and can be overused, but I thought there might be a use for one with this question, and the result was not disappointing:

[image]

The Ngram indicates that *what on earth* has seen its heyday, but isn't extinct yet.

Thumbing through the results of the book search, one can see that many of its modern uses are puns (such as the children's book entitled [*What on Earth Is a Meerkat?*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1567110932), which plays off how the word *earth* can be used in a biological sense, or the subtitle of Rick Warren's *The Purpose-Driven Life: [What on Earth Am I Here For?](http://books.google.com/books?id=ggWoFZSDlkcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22what%20on%20earth%22&source=bl&ots=eCw55PXJy7&sig=L9Dltyn3OTrljp144zhjmbtRXoE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cBIyUIT2J4mHywHbi4CICQ&ved=0CGIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22what%20on%20earth%22&f=false)*, which forms a theological pun.)

Still, the phrase still gets used as a good old-fashioned mild oath from time to time.  From a 2006 edition of **[Women's Health](http://books.google.com/books?id=1cUDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22what%20on%20earth%22&source=bl&ots=of9P0gbYoo&sig=2B-rU74H445cJlQDnWh99sjsv4U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qREyUMCOG6aZyAGyh4CgBA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwADgo#v=onepage&q=%22what%20on%20earth%22&f=false)** magazine:

[image]

As for alternatives, there's always *"Heavens to Betsy!"* but that probably sounds more outdated than "*What on earth...*"

Comment: In my part of the world we had "Heavens to Murgatroyd!", though I have seen several websites saying it is American in origin.

Comment: @RoaringFish: There's quite a few alternatives I could have listed, but I opted to go with "Betsy" owing to the O.P.'s name :^)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the pun ... What would you use in real life spoken English?

Comment: @RoaringFish I remembered that Murgatroyd phrase from cartoons, then found a link explaining the origins here http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080707123703AA9IoCE

Comment: @Betty "Heavens to Betsy" is one of a few common ones, not just linked to your name.

Comment: "What the devil" should be in there, as well.  I'm hoping to see a spike late 80s/early 90s ;)

Comment: What in the world are you thinking? All this shows is that people did not often publish books with foul language before such-and-such a date. It says nothing about speech.

Comment: I have used "What the", with a slight pause, so the audience can fill in whatever word they feel is appropriate, so tchrist's line would be "What the ... are you thinking?"

Comment: @Betty: What would I really use? That's hard to say, it all depends on who I'm talking to, and how flustered I happen to be in the moment. "What the heck" might be one I'd say. There's also the phonetic alphabet, too; I've used "Whiskey Tango Foxtrot" to express incredulity on more than one occasion.

Comment: @tchrist: Agreed. :^) I think the most pertinent part of my answer is the quote from the mainstream magazine, which hints that the expression is not hopelessly outdated, and thus may still be heard in casual conversation every now and then. As for the Ngram, I use that tool a lot when doing preliminary research on a question; I only paste the ones that I think are interesting enough to share. Of course, they should almost invariably be regarded as one small piece of a bigger puzzle, and not a definitive answer.

Answer (score 10):

I live in the south of England and "What on earth..." is reasonably common. An alternative would be "What in heaven's name...". However, this is increasingly 'posh' sounding. I would have said these phrases are typically British (although possibly not — see the comment by KitFox).

Personally I would never/rarely use "What on earth..." in online discussion (simply because it's a bit long winded), however, I would in spoken English.

Comment: Thanks. To make sure I understood you, when you say "this is increasingly 'posh' sounding", you mean only "What in heavens name...", right? And by "these phrases" you mean both "What on earth..." and "What in heavens name...", right?

Comment: @Betty Yes, exactly.

Comment: I live in the northeast US.  I have two young children, so we use it all the time as an alternative to the "what the hell" that Grampy taught them.  It's common here.

Comment: @KitFox, does that mean you think "what the hell" is not fit for children and "what on earth" is better?

Comment: I have an aunt and uncle who won't buy pizza from [Hell](http://hellpizza.com/), because of the name.

Comment: I, too, live in south-east England, and 'what on earth?' is most certainly part of my linguistic repertoire. I wouldn't hesitate to use it, where appropriate, in online discussions.

Comment: @Betty Yes, 'what the hell' is not as bad as 'what the fuck,' but I don't feel it is appropriate for children to use.  'What the heck' would probably be OK, but my eldest kept getting 'heck' and 'hell' confused (which is hilarious, by the way: "What the heck? I mean, hell. I mean...Mommy, which one is the polite one again?").

Answer (score 7):

The technical term for this ia a *minced oath*, and you may be able to look up a list. The difficulty is that, like other oaths, they are more used in speech than in writing, and, being non-standard, they vary from place to place and among age-groups.  But I have heard *what the deuce, what the flip, what the hey*, and even *what the blank*, as well as the more usual *what the heck* and *what on earth*.

There is, of course, a rather more subtle point: while 'What on earth are you doing here?' just shows greater surprise than 'What are you doing here?', 'What the hell are you doing here?' is not a straightforward question; it shows anger, at least.  This may be one of the few places where bad language is actually necessary (to convey the full meaning).

Comment: "What on earth are you doing here?"  Does "on earth" modify "what" or the whole sentence?

Comment: @james: The former. *What are you doing here on earth?* would mean something different.

Comment: I would not have described "What on earth..." as a minced oath. It means something like "What possible explanation is there in the whole world  for your doing that?"

Answer (score 3):

I think 'what on earth' is [still used](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/jul/04/the-return-of-marxism), and [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+on+earth&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests that its popularity is on the increase again, at least in books.

Alternatives... 'what the devil', or 'what the blazes, or 'what the Dickens' was one my mother used.

Comment: "What the devil" is also cursing, like "what the hell", isn't it? And the last two, I have never seen. Thank you. :)

Comment: I thought 'what the devil' was quite tame, more so than 'what the hell' It is tame enough to be [used in a newspaper headline](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/religion/7421538/What-the-devil-is-going-on-at-the-Vatican.html)

Comment: "What in Sam Hill" was always a favorite of mine (and my wife's Grandmother).

Comment: "What in the world" works too!